# Do I need a stamp for the leave to enter in the UK under Tier 5 GAE?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

I am an EEA national and have a Tier 5 GAE visa valid for the UK.
The question is whether I need a stamp indicating the “leave to enter” with dates on my passport, to activate my visa, or not.
For example, am I able to access through the e-gates? I red that this may imply that I enter under a standard visitor status.

Comment: You would be entering the UK as a visitor if you plan to enter *before* the ‘valid from’ date of your visa. Does your decision letter tell you that you need to collect a BRP? Your sponsor/employer will need evidence of the date you entered the UK as part of ‘right to work’ checks

Comment: @Traveller no, no BRP for me since I've used the UK Immigration: ID Check app. Indeed the decision letter say that I've been granted entry clearance.

Comment: Then I think in theory you can use the e-gates https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/at-border-control However, if I were in your shoes, I would get a stamp.

Comment: @Traveller indeed, I made this question since some people have received a stamp (for shorter Tier 5 GAE, such as 4 months), while others have not (border official say it wasn't needed when asked about it). Honestly I would like not to have problem in the future if I leave and re-enter (of course during my Visa validity period)...